# Speed concerns of octree implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

For couple of days now I am trying to speed up my Force-Directed graph implementation. So far I've implemented Barnes-Hut algorithm that's using octree to decrease number of computations. I've tested it multiple times and number of force related computations is indeed drastically decreased. Below is the plot of computations to number of nodes without Barns-Hut (blue line) and with (red line):
[image: plot]
Even though now it should be a lot faster, the truth is that in the matter of speed (time) the upgrade is only few percent.

One part I suppose might be causing this is tree creation and elements in tree placing. Because elements are constantly moving I need to recreate tree each loop until some stop condition is reached. But if I will spend lot of time creating tree I will lost there time I've gained on force computation increase. That's my thinking at least. This is how I am adding elements in my main file loop:

```
void AddTreeElements(Octree* tree, glm::vec3* boundries, Graph& graph)
{
    for(auto& node:graph.NodeVector())
    {
        node.parent_group = nullptr;
        if(node.pos[0] < boundries[1][0] && node.pos[0] > boundries[0][0] &&
                node.pos[1] > boundries[4][1] && node.pos[1] < boundries[1][1] &&
                node.pos[2] < boundries[0][2] && node.pos[2] > boundries[3][2])
        {
            tree->AddObject(&node.second);
            continue;
        }

        if(node.pos[0] < boundries[0][0])
        {
            boundries[0][0] = node.pos[0]-1.0f;
            boundries[3][0] = node.pos[0]-1.0f;
            boundries[4][0] = node.pos[0]-1.0f;
            boundries[7][0] = node.pos[0]-1.0f;
        }
        else if(node.pos[0] > boundries[1][0])
        {
            boundries[1][0] = node.pos[0]+1.0f;
            boundries[2][0] = node.pos[0]+1.0f;
            boundries[5][0] = node.pos[0]+1.0f;
            boundries[6][0] = node.pos[0]+1.0f;
        }

        if(node.pos[1] < boundries[4][1])
        {
            boundries[4][1] = node.pos[1]-1.0f;
            boundries[5][1] = node.pos[1]-1.0f;
            boundries[6][1] = node.pos[1]-1.0f;
            boundries[7][1] = node.pos[1]-1.0f;
        }
        else if(node.pos[1] > boundries[0][1])
        {
            boundries[0][1] = node.pos[1]+1.0f;
            boundries[1][1] = node.pos[1]+1.0f;
            boundries[2][1] = node.pos[1]+1.0f;
            boundries[3][1] = node.pos[1]+1.0f;
        }

        if(node.pos[2] < boundries[3][2])
        {
            boundries[2][2] = node.pos[2]-1.0f;
            boundries[3][2] = node.pos[2]-1.0f;
            boundries[6][2] = node.pos[2]-1.0f;
            boundries[7][2] = node.pos[2]-1.0f;
        }
        else if(node.pos[2] > boundries[0][2])
        {
            boundries[0][2] = node.pos[2]+1.0f;
            boundries[1][2] = node.pos[2]+1.0f;
            boundries[4][2] = node.pos[2]+1.0f;
            boundries[5][2] = node.pos[2]+1.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is go through all my elements in graph and add them to tree root. Also, I am extending my box that is representing my octree borders for next loop, so all nodes will fit inside.

Fields important to octree structure update are as follows:

```
Octree* trees[2][2][2];
glm::vec3 vBoundriesBox[8];
bool leaf;
float combined_weight = 0;
std::vector<Element*> objects;
```

and part of code responsible for update:

```
#define MAX_LEVELS 5

void Octree::AddObject(Element* object)
{
    this->objects.push_back(object);
}

void Octree::Update()
{
    if(this->objects.size()<=1 || level > MAX_LEVELS)
    {
        for(Element* Element:this->objects)
        {
            Element->parent_group = this;
        }
        return;
    }

    if(leaf)
    {
        GenerateChildren();
        leaf = false;
    }

    while (!this->objects.empty())
    {
        Element* obj = this->objects.back();
        this->objects.pop_back();
        if(contains(trees[0][0][0],obj))
        {
            trees[0][0][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][0][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[0][0][1],obj))
        {
            trees[0][0][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][0][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[0][1][0],obj))
        {
            trees[0][1][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][1][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[0][1][1],obj))
        {
            trees[0][1][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][1][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][0][0],obj))
        {
            trees[1][0][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][0][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][0][1],obj))
        {
            trees[1][0][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][0][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][1][0],obj))
        {
            trees[1][1][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][1][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][1][1],obj))
        {
            trees[1][1][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][1][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
            {
                trees[i][j][k]->Update();
            }
        }
    }
}

bool Octree::contains(Octree* child, Element* object)
{
    if(object->pos[0] >= child->vBoundriesBox[0][0] && object->pos[0] <= child->vBoundriesBox[1][0] &&
       object->pos[1] >= child->vBoundriesBox[4][1] && object->pos[1] <= child->vBoundriesBox[0][1] &&
       object->pos[2] >= child->vBoundriesBox[3][2] && object->pos[2] <= child->vBoundriesBox[0][2])
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Because I am using pointers to move around tree elements I don't think object creation/destruction is an issue here. The one place I suppose might have impact on speed is this one:

```
Element* obj = this->objects.back();
this->objects.pop_back();
if(contains(trees[0][0][0],obj))
```

Although I am not sure how I can ommit/speed it up. Does someone has any suggestions what can be done here?

**EDIT:**

I've done some napkin math and I suppose there is one more place which might be causing major speed decrease. Boundries checking in `Update` method looks like is doing a lot and what I calculated is that the added complexity due to this is in worst case scenario:

number_of_elements*number_of_childern*number_of_faces*MAX_LEVELS

which in my case is equal to number_of_elements*240.

Can someone please confirm if my idea is reasonable?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mihai I've posted it there after your suggestion: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127693/speed-concerns-of-octree-implementation

Comment: What DrunkCoder says is probably going to help, but remember the first three rules of performance optimizations: measure, measure, measure! Use a sampling CPU profiler for your platform (e.g. perf+hotspot on Linux, Visual Studio profiler on Windows or Instruments on macOS) and then use that data to find the performance culprits.

Answer (score 6):

If I understood correctly, you're storing a vector of pointers in every single octree node?

```
std::vector<Element*> objects;
```

...

```
void Octree::AddObject(Element* object)
{
    this->objects.push_back(object);
}
```

As I understood from this code, for octree building, your parent nodes `pop_back` element pointers from a parent vector and start pushing back to transfer the appropriate elements to the children.

If that's the case, I can immediately say that's a major bottleneck without even measuring, as I've dealt with such octree implementations before and improved their building by over 10x as well as reducing cache misses on traversal by simply using a singly-linked list which, in this particular case, significantly reduces the heap allocations/deallocations involved as well as even improving spatial locality when compared against a boatload of tiny `vectors` (one per node). I'm not saying it's the only bottleneck, but it's definitely a significant one.

So if that's the case, this is what I suggest:

```
struct OctreeElement
{
     // Points to next sibling.
     OctreeElement* next;

     // Points to the element data (point, triangle, whatever).
     Element* element;
};

struct OctreeNode
{
     OctreeNode* children[8];
     glm::vec3 vBoundriesBox[8];

     // Points to the first element in this node
     // or null if there are none.
     OctreeElement* first_element;

     float combined_weight;
     bool leaf;
};
```

This is actually just a first rudimentary pass but should help a lot. Then when you transfer an element from parent to child, there's no pushing back and popping back and no heap allocations. All you're doing is manipulating pointers. To transfer an element from parent to child:

```
// Pop off element from parent.
OctreeElement* elt = parent->first_element;
parent->first_element = elt->next;

// Push it to the nth child.
elt->next = children[n];
children[n]->first_element = elt;
```

As you can see from the above, with the linked representation, all we need to do is manipulate 3 pointers to transfer from one node to another -- no heap allocations, no need to increase size, check capacity, etc. Further, you reduce the overhead of storing the elements down to one pointer per node and one pointer per element. One vector per node will tend to be quite explosive in memory use since vector can often take, say, 32+ bytes even when just default constructed since many implementations preallocate some memory on top of having to store the data pointer, size, and capacity.

There's still lots of room for improvement but this first pass should help a lot, more so if you allocate the OctreeElement* using an efficient allocator (free list or sequential allocator, e.g.) or store them in a stable data structure that won't invalidate pointers but offers some contiguity, like `std::deque`. If you're willing to do a little more work, use `std::vector` to store all the elements (all the elements for the entire tree, not one vector per node) and link the elements together using indices into that vector rather than pointers. If you use indices instead of pointers for the linked list, you can store all the nodes contiguously without bothering with memory allocators just using one big old `vector` to store everything as well as halving the memory requirements for the links (assuming 64-bit pointers and that 32-bit indices are sufficient instead if you could use indices).

If you use 32-bit indices you might also not need all 32-bits, at which point you can use, say, 31-bits and tuck that `leaf` boolean which is adding a lot to the size of the node (around 4 bytes with padding and the alignment requirements of the pointers assuming 64-bit for that boolean field) into the first element or just set the first child index to `-1` to indicate leaves, like so:

```
struct OctreeElement
{
     // Points to the element data (point, triangle, whatever).
     int32_t element;

     // Points to next sibling.
     int32_t next;
};

struct OctreeNode
{
     // This can be further reduced down to two
     // vectors: a box center and half-size. A
     // little bit of arithmetic can still improve
     // efficiency of traversal and building if
     // the result is fewer cache misses and less
     // memory use.
     glm::vec3 vBoundriesBox[8];

     // Points to the first child. We don't need
     // to store 8 indices for the children if we
     // can assume that all 8 children are stored
     // contiguously in an array/vector. If the
     // node is a leaf, this stores -1.
     int32_t children;

     // Points to the first element in this node
     // or -1 if there are none.
     int32_t first_element;

     float combined_weight;
};

struct Octree
{
     // Stores all the elements for the entire tree.
     vector<OctreeElement> elements;

     // Stores all the nodes for the entire tree. The
     // first node is the root.
     vector<OctreeNode> nodes;
};
```

This is all still very rudimentary and there's so much room for improvement of a kind I can't really cover in one answer, but just doing these few things should already help a lot, starting with avoiding a separate `vector` per node as your biggest improvement.

**Linked Lists for Reduced Heap Allocations and Improved Locality of Reference**

This is something I feel like a lot of C++ developers I've worked with in the past have either forgotten or maybe never learned, but linked lists don't have to always translate to increased heap allocations and cache misses, especially when each node doesn't require a separate heap allocation. If the point of comparison is a boatload of teeny vectors, then linked lists will actually reduce cache misses and reduce heap allocations. Take this basic example:

[image]

And let's say the actual grid had 10,000 cells. In that case, just storing a 32-bit index per cell and linking elements together using 32-bit indices which are stored in one big array (or one big `vector`) is going to be much cheaper and require much fewer memory allocations (as well as typically much less memory) than storing 10,000 vectors. Vector is an excellent structure for storing non-trivial amounts of data, but it's not something you want to be using for storing a boatload of teeny variable-sized lists. There singly-linked lists can already be a substantial improvement and they're very well suited for transferring elements from one list to another in constant-time and dirt cheap, since that only requires manipulating 3 pointers (or 3 indices) without any additional branching.

So there's plenty of use still for linked lists. They're especially useful when you are actually using them in a way that reduces, rather than increases, heap allocations.

Comment: Potentially stupid question: how is this linked list more cache-local?